# iOS 10.0 to iOS 11API Differences

Tags: ios, ios10, ios11

Is there any way how to get something similar like we have for iOS10 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS101APIDiffs/index.html

New documentation browser have api diff, but if you want to just get overview what have changes or new features, it's very tiring and slow to click on every single thing...
https://developer.apple.com/documentation?changes=latest_minor

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language. Someone created a similar diff but only for objc: [Apple Platform SDK API Differences](http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/)

> API diff reports for Apple platform SDKs as generated by objc-diff, which has a few limitations:
>
> - Objective-C only
> - Does not detect relocations across frameworks
> - Excludes:
>
>   - /usr/include
>   - IOKit.framework
>   - Kernel.framework
>   - Tk.framework